# How to draw a dynamic table using PHPDocx

Tags: php, phpdocx

Can anyone help me with some PHPDocx knowledge. I am trying to draw a dynamic table based on some data from the database. I want to have something like this:

[image]

I have a placeholder variable called `$table$` in the .docx file.

Answer (score 1):

write html table and convert to docx formate.

```
require_once 'classes/CreateDocx.inc';

$docx = new CreateDocx();
$docx->addTemplate('testHTML2mdc.docx');

$docx->replaceTemplateVariableByHTML('ADDRESS', 'inline', 'C/ Matías Turrión 24, Madrid 28043 Spain', array('isFile' => false, 'parseDivsAsPs' => true, 'downloadImages' => false));
$docx->replaceTemplateVariableByHTML('CHUNK_1', 'block', 'http://www.2mdc.com/PHPDOCX/example.html', array('isFile' => true, 'parseDivsAsPs' => true, 'filter' => 'capa_bg_bottom', 'downloadImages' => true));
$docx->replaceTemplateVariableByHTML('CHUNK_2', 'block', 'http://www.2mdc.com/PHPDOCX/example.html', array('isFile' => true, 'parseDivsAsPs' => false, 'filter' => 'lateral', 'downloadImages' => true));

$docx->createDocx('webpage');
```

you can modify this code or refer this [link](http://www.phpdocx.com/news/post/convert-html-to-word-with-php/169)